# Android layout not coming ok

Tags: android, layout

I want following layout in my app.
A button at top, second botton at bottom and third occupying the whole middle space. Following code I am using bt it is not showing the second button. How to achieve the result ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">
           <!--view=2-->

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" 
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Previous" 
  />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Next" 
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can also use RelativeLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it through Relative Layout

Here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <!-- view=2 -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Previous" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Next" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Quoting OP's Second Question

> what if in the top row there are three buttons, then what reference
>   shall i use in android:layout_below

Here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- view=2 -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It will give you following output

[image]

Comment: what if in the top row there are three buttons, then what reference shall i use in `android:layout_below`

Comment: You can use any buttons id from 3 buttons

Comment: does `orientation` has any meaning in `RelativeLayout` . i experimented with both values, it does not make any change.

Comment: Ohh my mistake it shouldn't be there :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <!-- view=2 -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:text="Previous" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks SpK.....:) let him provide a bunch of options to chose one as per his need ......

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

           <!--view=2-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Previous" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button5"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead. Try to place the buttons from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

This is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- view=2 -->

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/button5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Previous" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to try this as you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="9">


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Save" 
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
     android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Previous" 
  />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
     android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Next" 
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

this layout divides buttons as you want if you want to change screen occupied just modify the weight of that button..
But i suggest you to use Relative layout instead which makes your work easy..